# Execute Flask API and maintain Session not working

Tags: python, ajax, session, flask

I am new to **flask apis**. In simple words, I have created a web page **index.html** in **apache** which is running on **localhost (default port is 80).**

Now I have a **2 flask APIs**,

running on **locahost:5000/set_session**. => To **set** session value

running on **locahost:5000/get_session**. => To **get** session value

**index.html**

Call to **locahost:5000/set_session** to **set** session.

```
$.ajax(
    {
        url: "http://localhost:5000/set_session",  
        type: "GET",
        success: function(response) {}
    }
);
```

Call to **localhost:5000/get_session** to **get** the session.

```
$.ajax(
  {
    url: "http://localhost:5000/set_session",  
    type: "GET",
    success: function(response) {}
    }
);
```

I have **app.py** in flask where I added **2 routes**.

```
**To set session value:**

@app.route("/set_session", methods=['GET'])
def setSession():
    session["user"] = "test"


**To get session value:**

@app.route("/get_session", methods=['GET'])
def getSession():
    print "Get session: ", session["user"]
```

Session is correctly set using **/set_session** not when I have trying to get the session value, It throws **error** into **flask route function** during **/get_session** which seems that **no session is available** to retrive.

Comment: Please show the full traceback so we can help you

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find some solution ?